# Explicit expression for recursive sums - II

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, recurrences

A twist on [just unfolded](https://mathoverflow.net/q/422075) recursive summation formula. Let polynomials in nonnegative integer variables $t_1,t_2,\dots$ be defined by the recurrence:
\begin{split}
g_0 &= 1, \\
g_k(t_1,t_2,\dots,t_k) &= \sum_{j=0}^{t_1} g_{k-1}(t_2+j,t_3+j,\dots,t_k+j)\qquad (k\geq 1).
\end{split}
Can $g_k(t_1,t_2,\dots,t_k)$ be explicitly expressed in terms of $t_1,t_2,\dots,t_k$ or via known combinatorial entities?

---

First few values are:
\begin{split}
g_0 &= 1,\\
g_1(t_1) &= 1+t_1,\\
g_2(t_1,t_2) &= (1+t_1)(1+t_2) + \frac{t_1(1+t_1)}2,\\
g_3(t_1,t_2,t_3) &= \frac12 \left(t_1^{2}+\left(2 t_2 + t_3 +3\right) t_1 +\left(1+t_2 \right) \left(t_2 +2 t_3 +2\right)\right) \left(1+t_1 \right)
\end{split}

In the case of equal arguments, the values $\big(g_k(t,t,\dots,t)\big)_{k\geq 0}$ apparently represent the row sums of the $t$-th power of the matrix $T$ defined in [OEIS A097712](https://oeis.org/A097712) and also the $t$-th column of table in [OEIS A125860](https://oeis.org/A125860).

In particular, $\big(g_k(1,1,\dots,1)\big)_{k\geq 0}$ form [OEIS A016121](https://oeis.org/A016121) defined as the number of tuples $(a_1=1, a_2, ..., a_k)$ satisfying $a_i \leq a_{i+1} \leq 2a_i$ for each $i=1,2,\dots,k-1$.

Comment: It should be $a(n+1)=g_n(1,2,3,4,\ldots)$ in [A008934](https://oeis.org/A008934).

Comment: More generally a conjecture is $g_n(k-1, k, k+1, \ldots )=$ column $k$ of [A093729](https://oeis.org/A093729), for $k \ge 0$.

Comment: A generalization of this function and the one in the linked question could be:

$h_k(t_1,t_2,\dots,t_k):=\sum_{j_1=0}^{t_1} \sum_{j_2=0}^{t_2+s_1(j_1)} \sum_{j_3=0}^{t_2+s_2(j_1,j_2)} \dots \sum_{j_k=0}^{t_k+s_{k-1}(j_1,\ldots,j_{k-1})} 1$. For $g_k$ we have $s_n(j_1,\ldots, j_n) = \sum_{m=1}^n j_m$. Another interesting case is $s_n(j_1,\ldots, j_n) = rj_{n-1}$, for example with $r=2$.

Comment: It seems that B.W.J. Irwin tried some of these nested sums: see [A254439](https://oeis.org/A254439), [A002449](https://oeis.org/A002449) and [this](https://oeis.org/A002449/a002449.pdf) that includes a generalization and several example sequences, [A101481](https://oeis.org/A101481), [A132616](https://oeis.org/A132616). Maybe one day I will write a program to check if there is some other sequence left at the OEIS that can be expressed in this way.

Answer (score 3):

*I originally saw the idea that inspired me to this answer [here](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/98563?#comment-873712)*.

From the statement it follows that

$$
g_k(t_1, t_2, \dots, t_k) - g_k(t_1 - 1, t_2, \dots, t_k) = g_{k-1}(t_2+t_1, t_3+t_1, \dots, t_k+t_1).
$$

Generally, one can express shift in the argument of analytic function with the operator exponent

$$
f(x+a) = e^{a\frac{\partial}{\partial x}}f(x),
$$

Let's denote $D_k = \frac{\partial}{\partial t_k}$, then the recurrence above rewrites as

$$
(1-e^{-D_1}) g_k = e^{t_1 (D_2+D_3+\dots + D_k)}g_{k-1},
$$

We can't invert $(1-e^{-D_1})$ operator directly because it doesn't distinguish between $0$ and $1$.

However we know that $g_k(0, t_2, \dots, t_k) = g_{k-1}(t_2, \dots, t_k)$, hence we can just solve the equation above for higher degrees of $t_1$, meaning that it's sufficient to find $D_1 g_k$:

$$
D_1 g_k = \frac{D_1}{1-e^{-D_1}}e^{t_1(D_2+\dots+D_k)} g_{k-1}
$$

Now let $I_k$ be the integrating operator over $t_k$ such that $[t_k^0]I_k f(t_k, \dots)=0$, we can express $g_k$ as

$$
g_k(t_1, t_2, \dots, t_k) = \left[1 + I_1 \cdot \frac{D_1}{1-e^{-D_1}} \cdot e^{t_1(D_2+\dots+D_k)} \right]g_{k-1}(t_2, \dots, t_k).
$$

Substituting it for $g_{k-1}$ and up to the very end, we get

$$
g_k(t_1, t_2, \dots, t_k) = \prod\limits_{j=1}^k \left(1+I_j \cdot \frac{D_j}{1-e^{-D_j}} \cdot e^{t_j(D_{j+1}+\dots+D_k)} \right) \cdot 1,
$$

assuming that the product unravels left-to-right as $j$ grows and then is applied to the constant $1$.

#### Example for $k=1$

The expression in this case is simply

$$
g_1(t_1) = \left(1+I_1 \frac{D_1}{1-e^{-D_1}}\right) \cdot 1
$$

The exponent operator rewrites as

$$
\frac{D_1}{1-e^{-D_1}} = \frac{1}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-D_1)^{k-1}}{k!}} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{D_1}{2}+O(D_1^2)} = 1+\frac{D_1}{2}+O(D_1^2).
$$

When it is applied to $1$, it yields $1$, then $I_1 \cdot 1 = t_1$, as the integration makes sure that it is $0$ for $t_1=0$.

Then, adding $1$ the result is, indeed, $g_1 = 1+t_1$.

Comment: Thank you! This is quite a interesting but somewhat unusual representation, and I do not see right away what kind of benefits it provides. Say, can it be used to speed up evaluation of $g_k$?

Comment: I think, computationally you could use it to get the explicit representation of $g_k$ as a multivariate polynomial of $t_1, \dots, t_k$.

Generally you can compute the result of applying the polynomial $g(D)$ of $D=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ to the polynomial $f(x)$ as

$$
g(D) f(x) = [g(x^{-1})\{f(x)\}],
$$

where $[\cdot]$ and $\{\cdot\}$ are linear transforms such that $[x^k]=\frac{x^k}{k!}$ and $\{x^k\}=k!x^k$. I wrote a bit more about it some time ago in [this article](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/99646) for the univariate case.